# Referencing an ASP control within a LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

Another total newb question, I'm afraid: I have a **LoginView** with some **HyperLinks** inside it, but when I try to reference the HyperLink in the code behind it tells me that it doesn't exist in the "current context".

eg. `hypLink1.NavigateUrl = "some/link/on/my/site.aspx"`

I've figured out that it's only because it's in the **LoginView** that it can't find it... so what can I do to tell it to look inside the LoginView?

I thought it might be something intuitive like:

`LoginView1.hypLink1.NavigateUrl = "some/link/on/my/site.aspx"`

But to no avail.

Thanks for any help with this (most likely) really obvious problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're trying to reference the hyperlink from outside the loginview control?

At that point, you could try a FindControls operation on the LoginView:

```
HyperLink hypLink1 = (HyperLink)LoginView1.FindControls("hypLink1");
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I was confused as to what you were asking.  The LoginView control only allows FindControls, and so you have to use the code snippet up above in order to reference controls internal to it.

Since the LoginView control uses templates, different controls will exist under different circumstances.  As such, the code cannot ensure any given control inside the template will be alive at compile time.

So you'll have to FindControls every time you want to get a child control :'(

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. How would I reference the Hyperlink from INSIDE the control, do you know?